# How to ignore keyword Function in SQL

Tags: sql

I have column that is named Function, when I try to filter records by Function column I'm getting an error(Incorrect Syntax near 'Function').

```
SELECT Week,ScheduleId, Line, OperatorId, Function FROM ScheduleRecords  as tbl WHERE Created > '2023-03-12' and Shift = 3 and tbl.Function = 'Operator';
```

Comment: You can use double quotes around it